# Linux C read single byte?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I'm working in JNA to call C functions, and I'm quite used to the Java `read()` function which reads a single byte. Is there a way to do this in C without declaring a buffer?

Comment: yes.. you can.. you can pass the address of single byte char as argument of read(), and give read size as 1.

Comment: To clarify: Does `without declaring a buffer` mean on the heap or stack?  (Or both?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char oneByte;
int r=read(fd, &oneByte, 1);
```

Yes, should work.

Comment: "Yes, should work" hardly engenders a sense of confidence :-) I'd suggest actually explaining the actual outcomes (i.e., check `r`) since there are situations in which that code _won't_ read a character.

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the constraint "without declaring a buffer".  The declaration of oneByte is clearly a declaration of a buffer.

Answer (score 2):

That depends if you want to read a stream (ie, a FILE *) or a file descriptor.

For a stream, you have

```
getc(FILE *stream);
```

For a file descriptor, you can use a byte variable as a buffer,something like

```
unsigned char b; //or signed if you prefer
read(fd, &b, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the answers that suggest using read(), it should look like this:

```
char b;
int r;
while((r=read(fd,&b,1))==-1 && errno==EINTR) {}
if(r==.....
```

The reason is that in case of delivery of a signal read() gets interrupted and needs to be restarted. If you do not test for EINTR you may face random, hard to find bugs.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a good idea, I'll have to figure out how to do that in Java. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getchar()` to get a single byte from standard input, or `fgetc()` to get it from an arbitrary file handle (stream), such as one of:

```
int ch = getchar();
// Assuming ch >= 0, you have your byte
```

or:

```
FILE *in = fopen ("input.txt", "r");
// should check for NULL return
int ch = fgetc (in);
// Assuming ch >= 0, you have your byte
```

If you have a file descriptor rather than a handle, you can use `read()` instead, something like:

```
int fd = open ("input.txt", O_RDONLY, 0); // should check fd for -1
char ch;
ssize_t quant = read (fd, &ch, 1);
// Assuming quant > 0, ch will hold your byte
```